# Calling SwiftUI button with action?

Tags: swiftui, swift5

I have a struct like this. How do I call SwiftUIButton with action?

```
struct SwiftUIButton: View{
        let action: () -> ()
        var body: some View{
            Button(action: action){Text("Tap me")}
        }
    }
```

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your code. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: How to call this button?  SwiftUIButton(action: !!!)

Comment: Replace the `!!!` with the thing you want to do when the button is tapped, I guess? Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is

```
    SwiftUIButton {
        // do anything here
        print(">> button tapped")
    }
```

which is the same (but short variant) of

```
    SwiftUIButton(action: {
        // do anything here
        print(">> button tapped")
    })
```